# How do I prove that solutions to the simple pendulum differential equation are always periodic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

I want to prove that all nontrivial solutions to the second order ODE $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\sin(x)$, for all initial conditions are always periodic functions. The idea I had was to convert it to a system of first order differential equations and calculating the Jacobian, but how can one then conclude the periodicity of the solutions?

Comment: I think you can use conservation of energy (energy is bounded) and uniqueness of solutions in order to indirectly show periodicity of solutions. And you must be precise what you mean by all nontrivial solutions. there are solutions which are not periodic in the angle $x$.

Comment: @MachineLearner By nontrivial solutions I mean solutions that do not pass throught the point $(x, \dot{x})=(0,0)$ of the phase space.

Comment: There are some solutions that are definetly not periodic in $x$ (https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Phase-portrait-of-the-physical-pendulum_fig42_267236399).

Comment: You can write the solutions of this ODE in terms of the Jacobi Amplitude functions: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html, which are inverses of the elliptic integrals of the first kind. One integration is pretty straight-forward: $\dot{x}^2=2\cos(x)+C_1,$ which you can get by multiplying through by $\dot{x}.$ Some Jacobi Amplitude functions are definitely not periodic.